# How to make a product categories navigation

Tags: php, html, html-table

I'm trying to make a navigation for a "product catalog" with categories and sub categories something like this:

1. Paper

   1. Xerox Paper
   2. Writing Paper

      1. Artist Paper
2. Writing tools.

And so on.

I'm having trouble finding a good tutorial or at least a good starting point about table structure and how everything should look. If someone can help me I'd appreciate it. I spent the entire weekend on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of navigation you have to create `4 tables` -

1) cat_listing
2) cat_listingtype
3) cat_listingsubtype
4) cat_typesubtype

```
1) cat_listing -
   id, 
   title, 
   listing_type_id (FK from `cat_listingtype`)

2) cat_listingtype -
   id, 
   title

3) cat_listingsubtype -
   id,
   title

4) cat_typesubtype - 
   id,
   type_id (FK from `cat_listingtype`)
   subtype_id (FK from `cat_listingsubtype`)
```

Comment: you can do it in one table because we do not know how deep one category will go

Comment: for the moment it won't go very deep but we didn't decide yet how our categories will look we are still discussing this part, for the moment we are thinking to have only two levels or maybe three.

Comment: why don't you design now such that in future you don't need to change the design of tables and source code

Comment: well that's what i want to do :-) because in the future a lot of things might change around and i don't want to do  the same thing twice :-).